# Criar uma extensão para visual studio que adicione classes dinamicamente

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Estou a criar um extensão para o visual studio que tem como objetivo criar um projecto com base nas opções que o programador quiser. Neste caso será criado um wizard onde ele vai escolher a(s) entidade(s) que quer criar, e com base nessa selecção serão criadas as respecivas classes.

Já criei o template (no meu caso vazio) e respectivo wizard para a selecção das entidades. O wizard de selcção das entidades que é apresentado quando o utilizador criar o projecto está na imagem abaixo. O objectivo é que quando fizer OK seja criado um projecto com as classes que ele escolheu, por exemplo "ConsolidacaoSaldos" deve dar origem a uma classe dentro de uma pasta "Accounting"

A Duvida é como criar as classes dinamicamente com base na selecção.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
namespace Primavera.Extensibility.Wizard
{
    public class WizardImplementation : IWizard
    {
        private Modules frm;
        private string customMessage;

        // This method is called before opening any item that   
        // has the OpenInEditor attribute.  
        public void BeforeOpeningFile(ProjectItem projectItem)
        {
        }

        public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
        {
        }

        // This method is only called for item templates,  
        // not for project templates.  
        public void ProjectItemFinishedGenerating(ProjectItem
            projectItem)
        {
        }

        // This method is called after the project is created.  
        public void RunFinished()
        {
        }

        public void RunStarted(object automationObject,
            Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary,
            WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
        {
            try
            {
                // Display a form to the user. The form collects the classes checked 
                frm = new Modules();
                frm.ShowDialog();

                customMessage = Modules.CustomMessage;


                replacementsDictionary.Add("$custommessage$",
                    customMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        // This method is only called for item templates,  
        // not for project templates.  
        public bool ShouldAddProjectItem(string filePath)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parabéns por fazer algo acima da média, eu queria que as pessoas tivessem criatividade em fazer coisas pra facilitar a vida delas. Não sei nem se esse é ocaso, se não teria outra solução melhor, mas enfim, é legal, mesmo que tenha uma coisas que eu não gosto no código. Só faltou colocar qual é a dúvida.

Comment: @Maniero já reformulei a questão. A duvida é com criar dinamicamente as classes/pastas no projeto dinamicamente com base na selecção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é simples de fazer.

Tens de criar um item template com o modelo da classe que queresm adicionar ao teu projeto e depois é só fazer um ciclo para iterar sobre a coleção de objetos que tens.

```
EnvDTE80.Solution2 solution = project.DTE.Solution as EnvDTE80.Solution2;
string itemPath = solution.GetProjectItemTemplate("Class.zip", "CSharp");

string[] namespaceParts = type.Namespace.Split('.');
if (namespaceParts.Length == 4)
{
    string module = namespaceParts[2];
    string moduleType = namespaceParts[3];
    string className = type.Name;     

    ProjectItem rootFolder = project.ProjectItems.Cast<ProjectItem>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == module) ?? project.ProjectItems.AddFolder(module);
    ProjectItem itemEditors = rootFolder.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(itemPath, className + ".cs");
}
```